# Problems when trying to validate a received qr

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an application in xamarin android, which reads a qr code to bring information, I am performing a validation which should only allow the entry of equal data, but I find a problem and it is that at the time of validation if I read a qr , which does not meet the condition raised, this throws me an exception, which says:Unhandled Exception: 
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference 
This is my archive.cs:

```
public void HandleResult(ZXing.Result rawResult)
{
    string cadena = rawResult.Text;
    string[] arreglo = cadena.Split();
    if (arreglo[0] == "MOVIL:" || arreglo[0] == "MOVIL,")
    {
        arreglo[0] = arreglo[0].Replace("MOVIL:", "MOVIL");
        arreglo[0] = arreglo[0].Replace("MOVIL,", "MOVIL");
    }
    if (arreglo[0] == "MOVIL")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.Length; i++)

        {
            mainActivity.lbl_movil.Text = arreglo[1].ToString();
            mainActivity.lbl_placa.Text = arreglo[3].ToString();
            //mainActivity.lbl_tipologia.Text = arreglo[3].ToString();

        }
        mainActivity.scannerView.StopCamera();
        mainActivity.scannerView.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible;
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alerta.SetTitle("No hay compatibilidad");
        alerta.SetMessage("Por favor scanear un codigo correcto");
        Dialog dialogo = alerta.Create();
        dialogo.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: which **specific** line throws the exception?

Comment: the exception occurs when the condition is not met, that is, in the else block, when the alert is created

Comment: that doesn't answer my question, I asked which **specific** line causes it, not which general block of code.  `AlertDialog.Builder` takes a `Context` as a parameter, is that what you are passing?

Comment: is raised in AlertDialog.Builder is where the exception is raised and takes the context

Comment: @cosmosmulti Your `this` does not appear to be an Android Context